# How to get referrer url in playframework

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I want to redirect back to referrer url in playframework and I have tried to log this url after request by log function in controller:

```
@After
public static void log(){
    session.put("referrer", request.url);
}
```

It works but I don't want to write the same code in every controller. When I let all the controllers extend AbstractController class(which extends `play.Controller`) and put this code in to AbstracController, I received this error:

```
Unexpected error : Cannot read parameter names for public static void controllers.AbstractController.log()
```

Can anyone help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try adding this method in a utility object and annotate your controllers with @With

```
public class ControllerUtil extends Controller{
    @After
    public static void log(){
        session.put("referrer", request.url);
    }
}

@With(ControlerUtil.class)
public MyController extends Controller{
   public static index(){
      render();
   }
}
```

Alternatively annotate your log methods with @Util

**UPDATE**

Correct, you need to have your ControllerUtil extend Controller. If you prefer name it Application instead of ControllerUtil

Comment: It doesn't work. class ControllerUtil does not extends play.mvc.Controller. Therefore it doesn't have session variable? Am I miss something?

Comment: @JanusTroelsen: Play-1.2.3

Answer (score 1):

```
request.headers.get("referer");
```